# Cakephp containable converting object to array

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using Cakephp's containable behavior to fetch some data. I have a belongsTo relationship that does not require a belongsTo object to always be present. This is fine but the issue is that Cake returns an empty array when this is the case. This is problematic for the API as if an object is present it's a JSON object but if an object isn't present it's a JSON array. Is there a way with containable to only include the results if a associated model is found?

Comment: If you can change belongsTo to hasMany on the fly just for this action, cake will return an array in both cases. I don't know any other method to achieve this.

Comment: I think there is no way to do that with containable. But you can check for empty relations on [afterFind](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) callback, and then delete them.